# How to replace particular substring using regular expression using java?

Tags: java

I have a string as below.

```
$Trap:com.oss.Event(description  matches  "abc")
```

In the above string the generic portions is `$Trap:com.oss.Event(<Any string>)`.

when i encounter the above string i need to replace with the below string.

```
$Trap:com.oss.Event(description  matches  "abc") from entry-point "EventStream".
```

To achieve the above i am using the following logic in java.

```
String stmt= $Trap:com.oss.Event(description  matches  "abc")

if(stmt.matches(".*\\.Event(.*).*")&& s.equals(""))
{
                stmt+=" from entry-point "+"ABCStream";
}
```

But the above logic is not working as expected when the string is as below.

```
stmt="$Trap:com.oss.Event(description matches "abc") or $Trap:com.oss.Event(description matches  "cde");
```

I need to generate the following corresponding string using regular expression.

```
$Trap:com.oss.Event(description matches "abc") from entry-point "ABCStream" or $Trap:com.oss.Event(description matches  "cde") from entry-point "ABCStream"
```

Please provide some pointers to achieve the same.

Comment: can't you just use String.Replace?

Answer (score 2):

The following Java code works:

```
String stmt = "$Trap:com.oss.Event(description matches \"abc\")"
   + " or $Trap:com.oss.Event(description matches  \"cde\")";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*?\\.Event\\(.*?\\)");
String res = p.matcher(stmt).replaceAll("$0 from entry-point \"ABCStream\"");

System.err.println(res);
```

and produces the following result:

```
$Trap:com.oss.Event(description matches "abc") from entry-point "ABCStream" or $Trap:com.oss.Event(description matches  "cde") from entry-point "ABCStream"
```

You need to quote special chars, e.g. round brackets, inside regexp and also use lazy match, i.e. *?. The $0 refers to the found matching group.

Using `Pattern.compile()` will save you some performance, if you are doing this replacement repeatedly.

Answer (score 2):

This do the stuff:

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String stmt="$Trap:com.oss.Event(description matches \"abc\") or $Trap:com.oss.Event(description matches  \"cde\")";
        System.out.println(stmt);
        System.out.println(stmt.replaceAll("(\\$Trap:com.oss.Event\\([^)]*\\))", "$1 from entry-point \"ABCStream\""));
    }
}
```

As you can see, you must double escape some symbols. The first and last parenthesis are for grouping the regex, and you can print that group with "$1"

And procuded this output:

```
$Trap:com.oss.Event(description matches "abc") or $Trap:com.oss.Event(description matches  "cde")
$Trap:com.oss.Event(description matches "abc") from entry-point "ABCStream" or $Trap:com.oss.Event(description matches  "cde") from entry-point "ABCStream"
```